# Intersecting data in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, intersect

I have 432 suburbs polygons and an open space dataset comprising polygons
I need to extract for each individual suburb the open space polygons inside and those which straddle the suburb boundary (Not perform a clip).
I have the advance licence of ArcMap[image]

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what you're trying to do, it's not clear what you have and where you're heading. It sounds like you don't want to clip, rather select layer by location with the boundary of your clipping polygon to find the open space units that cross the boundary (are inside *and* outside). Can you please indicate your license level, some of the involved operations may require an advanced license.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a text statement of your issue rather than relying on text in a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, what I think you need is the 'Select Layer by Location' tool:

- Data Management -> Layers and Table Views -> Select Layer By Location

This tool can be used to select all of the features in one layer that intersect with any of the features in another layer.

(In fact, you can choose from options other than intersect, but INTERSECT seems most appropriate for your query.)

Make sure that the input to this tool is a feature layer (not a feature class).  (The selecting features can be a feature class, and need not be a feature layer.)

If you wish to do this separately for each suburb, then select the suburb feature in the feature layer (or set a query definition on the feature layer) before running the 'Select Layer by Location' tool.

Comment: Thank you. I will work with this suggestion and see what the outcome is.

Comment: Did you get this working?